# Clear input upon onChange event

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'd like to clear the input field after a successful selection (in single selection mode) - I'm aware that this isn't a normal use-case so I'm not surprised I couldn't find a way to do it in the docs. Is there a workaround I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typeahead instance exposes a [public `clear` method](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Methods.md), which you can use in the `onChange` handler to reset the component after a successful selection:

```
const MyTypeahead = () => {
  const typeaheadRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Typeahead
      ...
      onChange={s => {
        if (s.length) {
          typeaheadRef.current.clear();
        }
      }}
      options={[ ... ]}
      ref={typeaheadRef}
    />
  );
};
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rbt-clear-on-change-59kgq

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I couldn't work out how to access the public methods from within the onChange, I have a lot to learn about React!

Comment: Spend hours on this. If you're getting `this is not a function` error then probably need upgrade the package https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/631