# React-Bootstap-Typeahead: Manually set custom display value in onChange() upon menu selection

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

In the `onChange` of React-Bootstrap-Typeahead, I need to manually set a custom display value. My first thought was to use a `ref` and do something similar to the `.clear()` in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753991/clear-input-upon-onchange-event).

But although `.clear()` works, `inputNode.value = 'abc'` does not work, and I'm left with the old selected value from the menu.

```
onChange={option => {
     typeaheadRef.current.blur(); // This works
     typeaheadRef.current.inputNode.value = 'abc'; // This does not work (old value is retained)
}}
```

I also tried directly accessing the DOM input element, whose ID I know, and doing

```
var inputElement = document.querySelector('input[id=myTypeahead]');
inputElement.value = 'abc';
```

But that didn't work either. For a brief second, right after my changed `value =` , I do see the new display label, but then it's quickly lost. I think the component saves or retains the menu-selected value.

Note: I cannot use `selected`, I use `defaultSelected`. I have some Formik-related behavior that I've introduced, and it didn't work with `selected`, so I'm stuck with `defaultSelected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I found is to re-render the Typeahead component (hide and re-show, from a blank state) with a new `defaultSelected="abc"` which is a one-time Mount-time value specification for the control.

I couldn't get `selected=..` to work, I have a wrapper around the component which makes it fit into Formik with custom `onChange` and `onInputChange` and `selected` wasn't working with that.

So the simple workaround that works is, if the visibility of the Typeahead depends on some condition (otherwise it **won't** be rendered), use that to momentarily hide and re-show the component (**a brand new repaint**) with a new `defaultSelected`, e.g.

```
/* Conditions controlling the visibility of the Typeahead */
!isEmptyObject(values) &&
(values.approverId === null || (values.approverId !== null && detailedApproverUserInfo) 
)
&&
    <AsyncTypehead defaultSelected={{...whatever is needed to build the string, or the literal string itself...}}
     ..
     
   // Given the above visibility condition, we'll hide/re-show the component
   // The below will first hide the control in React's renders
   setFieldValue("approver", someId);
   setDetailedUserInfo(null);
   // The below will re-show the control in React's renders, after a small delay (a fetch)
   setDetailedUserInfo(fetchDetailedUserInfo());
```

Comment: It sounds from your original question as though you're trying to set a custom input value, in which case `defaultInputValue` might be more appropriate that `defaultSelected`, which sets the selected item(s). The approach would be the same, since external control of the input value isn't supported.